# How to set timeout/limit of Sahi

Tags: timeout, settings, behat, mink, sahi

I'm having a little trouble in finding a way to get the limit/timeout defined.

So I've looked around for a setting on a yaml that I could apply, but found nothing.
I've saw that the limit is set on [Behat\SahiClient\Client::__construct()](https://github.com/Behat/SahiClient/blob/master/src/Behat/SahiClient/Connection.php#L73).

So after a few headbangs against the laptop, I've ended with:

```
$this->getSession()->getDriver()->getClient()->setConnection(
        new \Behat\SahiClient\Connection(
            null,
            $this->parameters['rest_url'],
            null,
            null,
            1200
        )
);
```

This actually changed the value as I expected, but instead of having the following error from while to while:

```
Command execution time limit reached: `_sahi.setServerVarPlain("___lastValue___53c8d8e5cfd3a", JSON.stringify(document.URL))`
```

I get allways this one:

```
name lookup timed out
```

Any idea what I can be missing, or is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What version of Behat are you using?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about that
I'm using the version 2.5